# How can I launch Chrome with an unpacked extension?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, google-chrome-extension, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium WebDriver to test a Google Chrome extension I'm developing. I noticed that `ChromeDriver` can be customised to add extensions to the instance of Chrome that it launches. This can be achieved using the `AddExtension` and `AddExtensions` methods of the `ChromeOptions` class.

The documentation for these methods indicates that they require extensions to be provided as crx files. Since *I'm* developing the extension, I don't have a crx file. I would like to be able to load the unpacked extension, but I couldn't find a method to do this.

I tried putting the extension files in a zip file and specifying this for the `AddExtension` method, but this caused an exception to occur since it wasn't a crx file. I also tried passing in the directory containing the unpacked files, but this produced a `FileNotFoundException`.

How can I do this?

Comment: I have no idea what all of this means, but I upvoted your answer, because it does indeed seem like useful information.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by using the `AddArgument` method to directly pass the information to Chrome. Here's what it looks like in C#:

```
options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--load-extension=" + unpackedExtensionPath);
```

Comment: Can the same be done for the RemoteWebDriver, provided I have the unpacked extension on the client machine?

Answer (score 3):

For packed extensions (a .crx file)

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addExtensions(new File("/path/to/extension.crx"));
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

For unpacked extensions (a local folder)

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("load-extension=/path/to/extension");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

[source](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/extensions)

Comment: Second option would work only for local Selenium as `/path/to/extension` would not be available remotely.

Comment: My unpacked extension works when i load it manually, but when it is loaded by this method, there is an error saying "manifest file is missing or unreadable"

Comment: are you specifying the correct local path in the second line?

Answer (score 2):

It may be late but for future users:

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/extensions

Answer (score 1):

The unpacked extension error popped up for me and I requested for removing the restrictions in chrome which was enforced as organizational policy. Once the restrictions were removed, I am able to run the program with out any errors. ChromeBrowser-GPO-Deny - this was the one which was removed. You can check in Settings - Extensions - Check on Developer mode and see if the load unpacked extensions is checked once the restrictions are removed. You should be good then. All the above will work only when the chrome is not restricted.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a`python` example using `webdriver_manager`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# loading the extension Edit-This-Cookie
options.add_argument("--load-extension=./Edit-This-Cookie")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=options)

driver.get("https://google.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python3 it can be done like this:

```py
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("load-extension=/path/to/unpacked_ext")

driver = Chrome("/path/to/chromedriver", options=options)

# (optional) Look at the uploaded extension
driver.get("chrome://extensions")
```

Answer (score -1):

The Selenium documentation has an example like this for a packed ( not unpacked) extension:

```
capabilities.setCapability("platform", "Windows 8" );
capabilities.setCapability("version", "10");
capabilities.setCapability("name", testname);
capabilities.setCapability("screen-resolution", "1280x1024");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addExtensions(new File("/path/to/extension.crx"));
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
if (isLocal) driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: `addExtensions` seems to require a *crx* file, which represents a *packed* extension rather than an unpacked one.