# How to access chrome extensions using selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension

I am new to selenium, I have a selenium script that works fine for chrome, I could add the the extension to the chrome using the .crx file but how can I use the extension while testing with selenium. For Instance I have 'Resource Override' extension which replaces one of my javascript file with the custom file. I cannot open inspect element and trigger the extension as chrome driver does not allow us to do so.

1.I am not sure how can I get the extension to use my javascript file using selenium. The extension has a text field to provide a path to the file that needs to be replaced and and a text box to add custom javascript code.

2.Is it possible to dynamically have the application use my custom javascript file using selenium with out using mentioned extension. I want to find alternatives with out checking in my code.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Path/chromedriver");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.logfile", "/Path/sel_logs.log");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
LoggingPreferences loggingprefs = new LoggingPreferences();
loggingprefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, loggingprefs);         
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addExtensions(new File("/Path/0.6.2_0.crx"));          
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);          
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
driver.get("https://google.com");
```

Comment: Does this [http://stackoverflow.com/a/18994520/1746118] help?