# Add an unpacked extension from file Selenium node.js

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to know how i can add an unpacked extension that i have on my computeur to my chrome webdriver using this : 
https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/chrome_exports_Options.html#addExtensions
I don't really understand what im supposed to do with it..
Thanks in advance to everybody that will help me =)
P.S : Im using these node packages : selenium-webdriver, fs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
let chrome = require("selenium-webdriver/chrome");
let options = new chrome.Options();
options.addExtensions("/path/to/extension.crx")
let driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .setChromeOptions(options)
    .build();
```

Comment: Your example shows how to add a packed extension (.crx file).  Does this work for an unpacked extension as the question asks?

Comment: @augurar, I provided a solution for unpacked extension below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74839549/3917161

Answer (score 5):

```
import {Builder, Capabilities} from 'selenium-webdriver';
import {Options, ServiceBuilder, setDefaultService} from 'selenium-webdriver/chrome';
import * as chromedriver from 'chromedriver';
import * as path from 'path';
import * as fs from 'fs';

const encodeExt = file => {
  const stream = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(file));
  return Buffer.from(stream).toString('base64');
};

const service = new ServiceBuilder(chromedriver.path).build();
setDefaultService(service);

const driver = new Builder()
  .withCapabilities(Capabilities.chrome())
  .setChromeOptions(new Options()
    .addExtensions(encodeExt('./3.5.2_0.crx')))        <-----+
  .build();                                                  |
                                                             |
                                                             |
                  this line here! ----------------------------
```

And this is how to download the .crx file: https://www.maketecheasier.com/download-save-chrome-extension/

Answer (score 1):

The other 2 answers require a packed extension (`.crx`).

For unpacked extensions, use the following instead:

```js
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
let opt = new chrome.Options();
opt.addArguments("--load-extension=/path/to/extension");
let driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .setChromeOptions(opt)
    .build();
```

Here's a similar answer for C#: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18994520